# SCNNode is not being anchored at real world coordinates

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a simple SCNNode that I want to place in the real-world position, the node corresponds to a landmark with known coordinates. I want to keep the SCNNode still at its location, however it tends to move with the camera. I cannot use plane detection or a hit-test to place the node in the real-world, I can only use the real-world coordinates. My current solution creates an ARanchor using the SCNNodes world transform.

```
showNode(node: Node, location: convertedPoint)
let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: Node.simdWorldTransform)
self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
```

I thought this would be enough to anchor the node. Is there a solution to anchor the node without using plane detection or a hit-test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, even if you stabilize your node with an anchor, it's never going to be perfect, just better.

However, while an ARAnchor is being created at the coordinates you are telling it, but the node you want to be stabilized is not actually being placed within that anchor.

You need to implement the `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor)` function in your `ARSCNViewDelegate` and return the target node you want to be stabilized by the anchor (Alternatively, you can add your node as a childNode of the default created anchor node by implementing the `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` function).

If your `nodeToBeStabilized` object is available as property within the ViewController, then a very dumb implementation might be something like this:

```
extension WAViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        return nodeToBeStabilized
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your solution with no success. The node keeps jumping around erratically. I have edited my original question to give a better understanding of my code. I'm still not sure where I am going wrong? Is there a conflict with assigning my position to the node?

Comment: If you have plane finding on, then it could be that `nodeAdded` is getting added to different plane anchors whenever they are found. If that's the case, you could add a name to your anchor (`anchor.name = "geomAnchor"`), and then check for that name before returning your `nodeAdded`, otherwise return `nil`.

Comment: Is the AR anchor placed based on the world origin or the cameras view? I am setting a new world origin (translating the y-axis) and then defining the placement of SCNNodes based on this new origin, therefore can I assume the same is happening for the anchors? If not, do I need to offset the node.simdworldtransform by the same height difference I apply to the world origin? I'm not too sure if the anchoring is actually improving after implementing your previous solution